# Button can only be clicked once (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to this.
When I click on the button to rebind the jump key, the rebind works fine. First the panel "Waiting on rebinding..." pops up, then I press the key, I want jump to be, then the new key shows up on the button as the binding.
This works only once though. When I want to click on the same button again, it doesn't allow me to click on it. The button doesn't even change color anymore, when you hover over it.

[image]

What I tried to solve this was to duplicate the button. When I click on either of the buttons and rebind the jump key, it works the first time, but not after that. Both buttons are unclickable. Closing and opening the button panel doesn't work either.

Here is the code for the OnClick() on the button:

```
public void JumpStartRebinding()
        {
            startRebindObject.SetActive(false);
            waitingForInputObject.SetActive(true);

            movement.PlayerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("UI");
            jumpAction.action.Disable();

            rebindingOperation = jumpAction.action.PerformInteractiveRebinding()
                .WithControlsExcluding("Mouse")
                //.WithCancelingThrough("<Keyboard>/escape")
                .OnMatchWaitForAnother(0.1f)
                .OnComplete(operation => JumpRebindComplete())
                .Start();
        }

        private void JumpRebindComplete()
        {
            int bindingIndex = jumpAction.action.GetBindingIndexForControl(jumpAction.action.controls[0]);

            bindingDisplayNameText.text = InputControlPath.ToHumanReadableString(
                jumpAction.action.bindings[bindingIndex].effectivePath,
                InputControlPath.HumanReadableStringOptions.OmitDevice);

            jumpAction.action.Enable();
            rebindingOperation.Dispose();

            startRebindObject.SetActive(true);
            waitingForInputObject.SetActive(false);

            movement.PlayerInput.SwitchCurrentActionMap("Player");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue doesn't appear to be with your code. I was having this exact same issue a few days ago. It likely has to do with the fact that a UI object is "covering up" the button. A first step I'd take is making sure that nothing is obscuring your button after re-enabling it (often times, TextMeshProUGUI objects with "Raycast Target" enabled are the culprit).